# I can't select the Enroll MOK for secure boot on ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, secure-boot

I just did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Legion5. I checked for installing third party software and it prompt me for a password for Secure Boot, which I did. After installation was complete, the blue scree showed with 4 options. This screen doesn't do anything, I push the down arrow for selecting `Enroll MOK` to create the key but the selection doesn't move and stays highlighting `Continue Booting`. I'm not sure what's going on since I have watched several videos doing fresh installations with Secure Boot and people are able to move the selection up and down.

Does anyone has experience something similar and can shade some light?

Comment: Did you try moving the selection box with the Tab key?

Comment: Yes, I tried utilizing the tab key and the space-bar key.

Comment: It turns out that my humanascale docking station uses displaylink and linux doesn't play well with it. Even though one can make it work, that driver is not friendly with linux based on a video from LearnLinux.tv